# Geospatial representation of a room ?

Tags: geospatial

So I'm really not sure what I'm looking for but I'd like a "standard" way to describe a room and what's in it. This way I'd be able to say :

- (x,y) : my office
- (x1,y1) : coffee machine
- (x2,y2) to (x3,y3) : a wall

etc.

I hope I made myself clear :)

Cheers,

Comment: `So I'm really not sure what I'm looking for` - so are we. :-) Maybe you can explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Let's say I'm working on an application which needs to know where everything is in a room :
- where the wall are, so it can draw a map
- where the things are (like, the coffee machine) so it can, I don't know, rotate a webcam in its direction

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a rectangular coordinate system (if you are only interested in a 2d representation of the space) or a 3d Cartesian coordinate system if you wanted to record the height of objects and features as well.

The Cartesian coordinates system is an accepted standard for describing the position of points in space, it is incredibly well documented and should be easily implemented in any language.

The axis in the system are generally called the x and y axis, so it looks like you were thinking along theses lines already.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system